# Translate nested query SQL to EF

Tags: entity-framework

I have this table structure:

[image]

Classic many to many relationship. I want to get all the orders for products belonging to the category for a small number of products I provide. It may be easier to show the SQL that does exactly what I want:

```
select o.*
from [Order] o join Product p2 on o.FKCatalogNumber=p2.CatalogNumber
where p2.FKCategoryId IN 
 (select c.Id
  from Category c join Product p1 on p1.FKCategoryId=c.Id
  where p1.CatalogNumber in ('0001', '0002')
```

This example gives me all the orders belonging to the categories that catalog #'s 0001 and 0002 are in.

But I am unable to wrap my head around the equivalent EF syntax for this query. I'm embarrassed to say I spent half the day on this. I bet it's easy for someone out there.

I came up with this but it's not working (and probably not even close):

```
string[] catNumbers = {"0001", "0002"};

var orders = ctx.Categories
  .SelectMany(c => c.Products, (c, p) => new {c, p})
  .Where(@t => catNumbers.Contains(@t.p.CatalogNumber))
  .Select(@t => @t.p.Orders)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you have navigation properties on your entity classes? This can be done without them, but it's shorter if you can just run up and down the chain of nav properties - otherwise you end up doing lots of checks for FKs in lists of IDs...

Comment: Yes, there are navigation properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still nest queries in EF.  The following looks like it works for me:

```
string[] catNumbers = {"0001", "0002"};
var orders = ctx.Orders
            .Where(o => ctx.Products
                .Where(p => catNumbers.Contains(p.CatalogNumber))
                .Select(p => p.CategoryId)
                .Contains(o.Product.CategoryId)
             );
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[CatalogNumber] AS [CatalogNumber]
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[CategoryId] = [Extent3].[CategoryId]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[CatalogNumber] = [Extent3].[CatalogNumber]) AND ([Extent2].[CatalogNumber] IN (N'0001', N'0002'))
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use query syntax (which looks very similar to SQL) in LINQ, so if you're more comfortable with SQL then you may prefer to write your query like this:

```
string[] catNumbers = {"0001", "0002"};

var orders = from o in ctx.Orders
    join p2 in ctx.Products on o.FKCatalogNumber equals p2.CatalogNumber
    where 
    (
        from c in ctx.Categories 
        join p1 in ctx.Products on c.ID equals p1.FKCategoryId 
        where catNumbers.Contains(p1.CatalogNumber)
        select c.ID
    ).Contains(p2.FKCategoryId)
    select o;
```

As you can see, it's actually just your SQL query rearranged slightly, but it compiles as C#.

Note that:

- the `[Order] o` syntax for referencing tables is replaced by `o in ctx.Orders`
- LINQ enforces which way round you do the join condition so I had to flip your `on o.FKCatalogNumber=p2.CatalogNumber` to be `on o.FKCatalogNumber equals p2.CatalogNumber`
- instead of your `where p2.FKCategoryId IN (...)`, the equivalent c# is `(...).Contains(p2.FKCategoryId)`
- the `select` comes last, not first

but those are the only major changes. Otherwise, it's written just like SQL.

I'd also draw your attention to a distinction regarding this comment:

> the equivalent EF syntax for this query

The syntax here isn't specific to EF, but is just LINQ  - **L**anguage **In**tegrated **Q**uerying. It has two flavours: query syntax (sometimes called declarative) and method syntax (sometimes called fluent). LINQ works on just about any collection that implements `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, including EF's `DbSet`.

For more info on the different ways of querying, [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) is a decent place to start. There's also [this handy reference table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882642.aspx) showing the equivalent query syntax for each method-syntax operator, where applicable.